Check if there are 3 numbers in array whose XOR is equal to zero
Given array of N real numbers x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, check if there exists 1 <= i,j,k <= n such that x_i ⊕ x_j ⊕ x_k = 0, where ⊕ is XOR operation.
This is college homework and it has to be done in O(N^2) time complexity.
My first thought is to change desired equation to x_i ⊕ x_j = x_k. Then for every number in array, pick it as x_k and try to find two numbers whose XOR is equal to it.
Then to solve this 2-XOR problem I thought about making trie of binary representation of numbers in array, so each node in trie is single bit of some number, and every path from root to leaf represent whole number.
Then using two pointers start at the root and look at the first bit of x_k. If its 1 then one pointer needs to go to 1-node and second one the 0-node. Problem here is that if some bit of x_k is 0 then our pointers can either go to two 1-nodes or two 0-nodes. It seems like I need to check both options but now I don't really now how that affects complexity. It seems that worst case scenario we will just traverse all nodes in trie every time so I'm not sure what is the complexity.
I don't care about code, I just need an idea and approximation of time complexity.

Could you be more specific about the numbers / machine model? XOR on real numbers doesn't make much sense to me. Can we assume that the "real numbers" have finitely, or even constantly, many bits, as is the case on real-world machines?

@Luatic You're right, original task was "now solve 3-SUM with XOR instead of sum in O(n^2)". So I just went with real numbers like in original task. But I agree it doesn't make much sense and I would opt to solve it with assumption that numbers have constant size.

Take a 3-SUM solution and just change add and subtract to XOR

Please define XOR on real numbers.

What programming language you using or can you use, if multiple?

Given that x_i ⊕ x_j = x_k you can use hash map/set to remember x_i ⊕ x_j and x_k and check against them while iterating all array item combinations. That would give you no more than O(n^2) complexity. Also the x_i ⊕ x_j and x_k could be stored in sorted arrays (binary trees) with binary search involved.


const arr = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

const shuffle = arr => {
    const copy = arr.slice();
    return Array.from({ length: arr.length }, () => copy.splice(Math.random() * copy.length | 0, 1)[0]);
};


const hasXORs = arr => {

  const xors = new Map;
  const nums = new Set;

  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    const n=arr[i];
    if(xors.has(n)) return [...xors.get(n), n];
    for(let j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
      const n2 = arr[j];
      const xor = n ^ n2;
      if(nums.has(xor)) return [n, n2, xor];
      xors.set(xor, [n, n2]);
    }
    nums.add(n);
  }
};

console.log(...hasXORs(shuffle(arr)));



A simplified version with 1 set only:


const arr = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

const shuffle = arr => {
    const copy = arr.slice();
    return Array.from({ length: arr.length }, () => copy.splice(Math.random() * copy.length | 0, 1)[0]);
};


const hasXORs = arr => {

  const nums = new Set(arr);

  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(let j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
      if(nums.has(arr[i]^arr[j])) return true;
    }
  }
};

console.log(hasXORs(shuffle(arr)));




How I understand this is we basically iterate over all pairs of numbers from array, and check if their XOR is in the array using HashSet. When we do nums.has(arr[i]^arr[j]) and it returns true how do we know it didn't "find" number we already used? More specificaly what if arr[i]^arr[j] = arr[i] ? Then our set lookup is not correct because we are reusing same number from array. It can only happen when one of the numbers is 0 so maybe it's easy to fix.

Another point is it still worst case scenario O(n^2)? I know HashSet has expected time complexity O(1) but worst case scenario it is not. Can we guarantee that using HashSet with our data will always be constant? (My college course is very strict so I wonder if it's still O(n^2) worst case scenario with our data)

@mafju you can use a trie instead of the hash set.

This is linear as x_i ⊕ x_j ⊕ x_k is 0 either if all three are 0 or two of them are 1 and the other 0. Thus count the number of 0 and 1, if there is at least three 0 or one at least one 0 and at least two 1, you know that there will be values for i,j,k.
If you need the indices (i,j,k) you just have to keep some indices  through the parsing.
---- EDIT ----
Python code could be:
bits = [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 ]

n_0, n_1 = 0, 0
n_0_idx, n_1_idx = [], []

for i,b in enumerate(bits):
        if b==0:
                n_0+=1
                if len(n_0_idx)<3:
                        n_0_idx.append(i)
        else:
                n_1+=1
                if len(n_1_idx)<2:
                        n_1_idx.append(i)

print(n_0,n_1)
print(n_0_idx,n_1_idx)
if n_0==3:
        print(n_0_idx)
elif n_0>=1 and n_1>=2:
        print(n_0_idx[0],n_1_idx)
else:
        print("bad")

Not that we can also shortcut the loop as soon as the condition is met.

"you just have to keep some indices through the parsing.": I'm interested to see this part happen in linear time complexity. Please do share it.

@trincot we can remember at most three indexes for 0s and at most two for 1s. Can't we?

That you ask me a question seems to indicate that you find it too trivial to show how to implement this. I must be stupid, but I don't see it. Care to share it?

@trincot edit added

You Python code operates on a list/an array of bits, the question reads array of N real numbers. (Don't ask me for a definition of ⊕ for real numbers.) (In Not that we can…, Note is intended in all likelihood.)

@greybeard if we suppose that xor on real number is a xor on their binary representation, then we just have to loop over the bit representation. This complexity will be O(n*sizeof(binreprofreal)), thus again linear. We have to collect all possible 0 and 1 locations in each bit-turn and then compare if there a same three values in those. Complexity will be greater than linear but probably not more than n^2 (don't have time to dig on this).

This seems to assume that the inputs are booleans, or else that XOR is being interpreted as a boolean operation rather than a bitwise one.
